# Does internal energy U always depend on temperature T?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, energy, temperature, adiabatic

One thermodynamic identity is $\mathrm dU=T~\mathrm dS-p~\mathrm dV          + (\mu~\mathrm dN+\ldots)$. For a system of ferroelectric particles, which exhibit electric polarisation $P$ when exposed to electric field $\mathcal{E}$, the equation for energy of the system has a term $ đW=-~\mathcal{E}~\mathrm dP$.
The system undergoes an adiabatic process. So far, I've found that $ đQ=dU-\mathcal{E}~\mathrm dP$. If this holds true, then $ đQ=T~\mathrm dS-P~\mathrm dV-\mathcal{E}~\mathrm dP$. (If the system is a rigid body, then $\mathrm dV=0$, and the term $P~\mathrm dV$ is $0$.) Considering that $ đQ=0$ for the adiabatic process, does the above equation imply that $Q$ is independent from $T$? If $Q $ is dependent on $T$, then how $ đQ$ can be $0$ while $T\gt 0$ and $\mathrm dS\gt 0$?

Comment: Hi @Grautus and welcome to [physics.se]. Please note [that this isn't a homework help site](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714/44126).

Answer (score 1):

The correct equation is: $dU=T~dS-p~dV-\epsilon ~dP$. If the process is adiabatic and $\textit{reversible}$ then $dS=0$. If there is no volume change either then we simply have $dU=-\epsilon ~dP$. Since the process is adiabatic $Q=0$ by definition. You cannot speak of $Q$ as depending on $T$ or any other state variable because $Q$ is not a state function. $Q$ is just flux of energy caused by difference in temperature between system and its surroundings.